# Polynomial Condition Number

Tags: polynomials, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a question, from "Applied Numerical Linear Algebra"(James W. Demmel), that I don't know how to do.

Consider $\mathbb{R^{d+1}}$ as the set of polynomials of degree $\leq d$ and $S_a$ the set of polynomials in $\mathbb{R^{d+1}}$ with infinite relative condition number at $a$, it means $S_a$ is the set of polynomials that have $a$ as root.
My task is to describe(in a few words) $S_a$ geometrically as a subset of $\mathbb{R^{d+1}}$.

After this I have also to describe $S_a(\kappa)$ geometrically, where $S_a(\kappa)$ is the set of polynomials whose relative condition number is $\kappa$ or greater, and finally, describe how $S_a(\kappa)$ changes as $\kappa\rightarrow\infty$.

*the relative condition number of a polynomial $p(x)$ is $|p'(x)|\cdot|x|/|p(x)|$. But the author also gives another way to define this relative condition number, you can also say that the relative condition number of a polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^da_ix^i$ is $\big(\sum_{i=0}^d|a_ix^i|\big)/|\sum_{i=0}^da_ix^i|$.

My observations:

1) $S_a$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^{d+1}}$;

2) the dimension of $S_a$ is at most $d$.

Although this observations look useful, I don't know how to use them to get some geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't very clear about what relative condition number at $a$ means, but you may use the fact that if $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{d} a_i x^i$ is a polynomial that have $a$ as root, then $p(x)$ factors as $p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$, where $q(x)$ has degree at most $d-1$, that is, $q(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} b_i x^i$. Now compare the coefficients in the both sides of $p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$ and you may get some idea of what $S_a$ looks like geometrically.

Comment: Im still trying to understand your idea.

Comment: I got it. With your idea its possible to say that $S_a=\{(x,0)-a(0,x)| x\in\mathbb{R}^d\}$.